# Why does using rppal's Uart to read a software-serial port on the Raspberry Pi not change the buffer?

Tags: rust, serial-port, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to read a sensor off of a software serial port (`ttySOFT0`) on the Raspberry Pi. I am using [soft_uart](https://github.com/adrianomarto/soft_uart) to get my serial interface.

The code is:

```rust
let mut port = Uart::with_path("/dev/ttySOFT0", 9_600, Parity::None, 8, 1).unwrap();
let mut buffer = [0u8; 9];
let command = [0xFFu8, 0x01u8, 0x86u8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x79u8];
port.write(&command)
    .expect("Could not write to the serial port");
port.read(&mut buffer)
    .expect("Could not read from the serial port");
let mhz19_high = buffer[2] as u32;
let mhz19_low = buffer[3] as u32;
let reading = mhz19_high * 256u32 + mhz19_low;
println!("{:?}", buffer);
```

The return value of the `port.write()` function is 0 but I expected to write 9 bytes. With `sudo` I write 9 bytes, but the buffer stays `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

This uses the [rppal](https://crates.io/crates/rppal) crate. I hadn't any luck with the [serial](https://crates.io/crates/serial) or [serial2](https://crates.io/crates/serial2) crates either.

There are no errors from the `.expect(...)`. I am  sure that there isn't a problem with the `soft_uart` driver as it works with sudo in Python:

```py
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttySOFT0')
packet = bytearray()
packet.append(0xFF)
packet.append(0x01)
packet.append(0x86)
packet.append(0x00)
packet.append(0x00)
packet.append(0x00)
packet.append(0x00)
packet.append(0x00)
packet.append(0x79)
ser.write(packet)
res = ser.read(9)
reading_co2 = res[2]*256+res[3]
```

Comment: May I ask how it came to your mind, that the Implementation is non-blocking? I didn't catch it, when I was debugging myself.

Comment: It didn't magically come to my mind — I read the documentation for `read` and `write` where it mentions that it's non-blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`Uart::read`](https://docs.rs/rppal/0.13.1/rppal/uart/struct.Uart.html#method.read) states (emphasis mine):

> `read` operates in one of four (non)blocking modes, depending on the settings configured by [`set_read_mode`](https://docs.rs/rppal/0.13.1/rppal/uart/struct.Uart.html#method.set_read_mode). **By default, `read` is configured as non-blocking**.

The same applies to `Uart::write` / `set_write_mode`.

Non-blocking means that if there is no data available, the call will return immediately with whatever data is available at that instant. Serial protocols are generally pretty slow compared to the rest of your computer, so this is a common occurrence.

You will need to adapt your code to handle this. A simple solution is to use `set_read_mode` / `set_write_mode` to make the calls blocking.

Another (better?) solution may involve retrying the `read` and `write` calls with delays until the buffer is sufficiently full.

Comment: Again, thank you very much!